# why does my preg_match not work with a variable but yes with a direct number?

Tags: php, preg-match

When I do this:

```
$row['id_number'] = 77088239;
$check = preg_match('/"'. $row['id_number'] .'"/i' , json_encode($list));
```

or if I get a number from a mySQL query in a database, it **doesn't** work, even if the string is in the `$list`. Even putting the number as `"77088239"` doesn't work either.

But when I do this:

```
$row['id_number'] = 77088239;
$check = preg_match('/77088239/i' , json_encode($list));
```

Then it **does** work. Why is that?

Comment: You need to remove `""` in your `preg_match`

Comment: Hah! How dopey of me. Thanks :)

Comment: also, why are you using regex to parse a json representation of a php object, when you could just check the content of the object directly, eg something like `$check = ($list->id == $row['id_number']);`

Comment: Json format offers structured data, use this structure and don't convert it to string to search something.